# Create a scrollable list of items and their properties in Winforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a class and a bunch of objects of that class; I would like to create a scrollable list displaying a list of these objects' properties. How could I go about this in windows forms?

I need to format it in a way that the user can add and take away from the list any time they would like.

To clarify, have a box that has 1 objects properties, the second thing in the list would have the other objects properties, etc.

I would like to do it in a visually pleasing way as well, not just text. Maybe have a box with all the things displayed in it.

I am using c#, if that helps.

PS: I am not asking you to do it for me, but for a way to go about doing it myself.

Thanks in advance to anybody who replies. If you need any more info I will gladly give it to you.

Comment: Show us what you have so far...

Comment: @Andy I have a class customer with a name, number, email, and address. That's literally it. I want to create a list to display these customers (when they come up) to the user without having to click a button to go the the next customer.

Comment: People are going to expect to see your work and what you've accomplished on your own. They want to see where you get stuck so they can help you through that part of the problem. Just asking for a solution will get you nowhere here.

Comment: @Andy I'm not working on some big project, I simply want to learn this skill to use in future projects. I'm not stuck anywhere, I just don't know how to do this

Comment: you are not stuck, you just don't know, - that's being stuck :-D ... what have you attempted so far? there are 1001 potential ways ... have you tried a DataGridView? Have you tried a Custom User Control? Or you do not know all the Controls yet - then literally its time to have a look at them and find out what they do.